# Swift PHPicker cancel button changes color

Tags: ios, swift, phpickerviewcontroller, phpicker

I am currently using the PHPicker from apple. Works great but whenever I switch to the album segment the cancel button changes colour to white, making it barely visible. When I switch back to all it stays white. Like so:

[image: View pops up]

[image: Switching to albums changes color]

code to initialise the picker:

```
        var config = PHPickerConfiguration(photoLibrary: .shared())
        config.selectionLimit = 50
        config.filter = .images
        let vc = PHPickerViewController(configuration: config)
        vc.delegate = self

        present(vc, animated: true, completion: nil)
```

Any idea?

Comment: Don’t you set any UIAppearance parameters?

Comment: Moreover please provide your code which initializes and shows the picker

Comment: @BulatYakupov I added the code. I don't change appearance on the picker, its fine if you open it but when you switch to albums it just changes the cancel buttons color.

Comment: I mean global UIAppearance parameter. For example for UILabel.

Comment: So basically it should work fine. There are two options why something is wrong here: 1) you messed up with appearance; 2) iOS bug‍♂️

Comment: Does it work fine on device? Maybe it’s simulator issue

Comment: Can you provide a project that demonstrates this with a reproducible example?

Comment: @matt will do that asap, seems the best way to test.

Comment: It's one of my primary debugging tricks! If you can't do it, that proves that the issue is due to something else going on in your code. And if you _can_ do it, you have the makings of a bug report.

Comment: @Mr_Bull3t Did you managed to fix the issue ?